# TypeScript React: RouteComponentProps types error or cant access history

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I have made a component and used it like...

```
<TopNav
    loggedIn={global.shared.loggedIn} // false 
    fullName={global.shared.fullName} // ''
    avatar={global.shared.avatarId} // ''
/>
```

and inside the TopNav components I want to be able to access the props I have passed in and `props.history` or some other way of navigating the user programatically without a refresh..

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';


interface PropsInterfaceNew {
  avatar: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  fullName: string;
}

interface PropsInterface
  extends RouteComponentProps<PropsInterfaceNew> {}
//                                    ^ Error

const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
...
 const firstName = props.fullName.split(' ')[0]; // I need props.fullName & others
  const search = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.history.push('/my/profile'); // I need props.history
  };
```

The error is

```
Type 'PropsInterfaceNew' does not satisfy the constraint '{ avatar?: string | undefined; loggedIn?: string | undefined; fullName?: string | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'loggedIn' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2344)
```

alternatively if I remove the history completely like the below I have no errors but no access to history

```
interface PropsInterface {
  avatar: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  fullName: string;
}

const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
...
```

@hardik if I replace `export { TopNav };` with...

```
  export withRouter(TopNav);
//^ err1      ^err2
```

I get the new error 2

```
statements are not aligned (align)tslint(1)
```

and error 1

```
Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)
```

Comment: I think we need to see more about your system. I just replicated your issue in a codesandbox except it works as expected on my end [**See Here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redirects-typescript-epom2)... Can you try and reproduce the issue in a codesandbox so we can understand more?

Comment: the sandbox has helped me edge closer, `export default withRouter(TopNav);` Use of default exports is forbidden (no-default-export)tslint(1) is there a way name the export?

Comment: sure, just assign an alias for it. `export const MyTopNav = withRouter(TopNav);` or with that same alias you can also `export { MyTopNav }` if you don't inline export it. Let me know if that fixes the issue and I'll write it up as a solution. If it doesn't please reproduce your error on the sandbox and post the link so we can determine what the particular issue is.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass `RouteComponentProps`, you have to wrap the component with `withRouter` and then export it.

```
export withRouter(TopNav);
```

and props type should be like,

```
interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps {
  avatar: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  fullName: string;
}

const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {....
```

This will definitely fix your issue!

Comment: I added your answer and the new errors it created above

Answer (score 4):

The `RouteComponentProps` interface from `react-router-dom` is used to describe the object that the router will pass to the component props. The generic parameter of the interface is used to describe the shape of the "match" object where the router stores values for all extracted route parameters.

As the route is always of string type, all matched route parameters can only be also strings, so the generic parameter must be a type that only has string properties. The problem is that your `isloggedIn` property is boolean. To satisfy the constraint it should be string.

But I'm not sure that is what you want, from your code it looks like `fullName`, `isLoggedIn` are not route parameters but props that are passed to component explicitly.
If that is the case you can type the props object like this

```
interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps {
  avatar: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  fullName: string;
}

const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {....
```

This gives you typed access to all router props (history, location, match...) and your additional props.

Comment: the parent component where i declare `<TopNav...` throws an error when it compiles now `Type '{ loggedIn: boolean; fullName: string; avatar: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'PropsInterface': history, location, match  TS2739`

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you have problem not only with `RouteComponentProps` but also with tslint config.

1. Use `interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps { /* ... */ }` as suggested by @Hardik Chaudhary.
2. Wrap `TopNav` with `withRouter` HOC. It will inject `history` prop to `TopNav` component. But other props, like `loggedIn` will stay intact
3. As you're not allowed to do default exports, do named export as below

   ```
   // don't export TopNav
   const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = /* ... */

   const TopNavWithRouter = withRouter(TopNav)

   export { TopNavWithROuter as TopNav }
   ```

   Now `TopNav` is wrapped with router props but exported as named export. You can continue using it like you did it earlier.

   ```
   import { TopNav } from './topnav.tsx'

   <TopNav
       loggedIn={global.shared.loggedIn} // false 
       fullName={global.shared.fullName} // ''
       avatar={global.shared.avatarId} // ''
   />
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your props as [Hardik Chaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5743249/hardik-chaudhary) suggested: You should use `interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps { /* ... */ }`, since the first type parameter of RouteComponentProps is not meant for props (it's used for [match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match))

And if you are going to export your component as default export, you should use `export default` instead of `export`. so your code should be `export default withRouter(TopNav);` and react-router will inject the props to your component as you expected.

Or if you prefer named exports, you can use `export const` to export your component with router props injected. I think this is probably your case since you used `export {...}` which is named export.

For convenience, I'll leave the full code with my suggestions applied below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps {
  avatar: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  fullName: string;
}

const TopNav: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => { /* ... */ }

// if you prefer default export
export default withRouter(TopNav);

// if you prefer named export
// Note: You must change the name of component above.
export const TopNav = withRouter(TopNav);
```